Не работает discord-бот на Python на другой ОС
Я написал простенького бота дискорд, на Windows 10 64 bit он работает, а на Windows 8 32 bit нет. Может ли быть проблема в битности системы?
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# бот для команд, выданы все намерения
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} запущен и готов к работе!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # если сообщение от бота - игнорируем
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    # проверяем, является ли сообщение командой
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command(aliases=['test', 'тест', 'тестовая_команда', 'test_command'])
async def test_(ctx):
    await ctx.send('<@&1141737318584156302> ')

# запускаем бота
bot.run('**********************************')

Бот рабочий, но именно на старом ноутбуке он запускаться не хочет.
ОШИБКА:
[2024-08-08 12:13:29] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1043, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs, sock=sock)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1110, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\BOT.py", line 20, in <module>
    bot.run('**********************************')
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 869, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 858, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 786, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 620, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 816, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 638, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1344, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 648, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 546, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 954, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1313, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1282, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1045, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')] 

ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО!

Попробуйте варианты решений из этого вопроса - возможно Вам помогут
